# How does Google Web Toolkits work with Servlets?

Tags: java, tomcat, gwt, servlets

I'm considering building a web app using Java and Google Web Toolkit and I have some questions.

I assume that when someone goes to a URL such as `http://site.com/Signup`, the Signup servlet will be loaded which will perform all the necessary work and forward the request to a JSP that would display the HTML and Javascript code.

If there is a certain javascript component that relies on a GWT component, it will be linked to from within the `<script type='...'></script>` tags.

If that's true, then is it possible to put the GWT code in the same project? Or do I need to create 2 projects, one for the Servlets/server-side code and one for GWT?

Another reason I'm asking this, is because when I create a new Dynamic Web project through Netbeans or Eclipse, it creates lots of folders such as build, dist, src, web, meta-inf, etc (I suppose these are due to TomCat), while when I create a project for GWT it creates some different folders. So my question is, can the two be merged together in 1 project, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres a [tutorial](http://lkamal.blogspot.com/2008/09/java-gwt-servlets-web-app-tutorial.html) on using GWT with your servlets.